# Is there a limit for DensityHistogram data amount?

Tags: data, system-limitations

I'm trying Mathematica for first time and while trying to do a Density Histogram with around **300 000** points, I get an error "*THE INPUTED DATA* is not a valid dataset or list of datasets."

Maybe it's the formatting,but if I do it (the Histogram) with handmade data, I get the Histogram. So my questoin, as mentioned above is: Is there a limit amount of data for the Histogram, Or is my  formatting mistaken? Which, by the way has the following structure:

```
  {
   {X1,Y1},
   {X2,Y2},
    ....
   {Xn,Yn},
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two-dimensional histogram figure works for me (v. 10.0.0) for 300000 data points:

```
mydata = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], {300000, 2}];
DensityHistogram[mydata]
```

[image: HistogramFig]

I did get your error message when I accidentally had extra `{  }` around my data set.  Check that for your data.  You can do that by `Dimensions[mydata]`.

Comment: I had no problem with 10^6 points: `mydata = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10^6, 2}];`